# Hook block save

Tags: 7, hooks, blocks

I have to perform certain operations when block configurations are get changed. And I successfully implemented `hook_block_save()` and worked.

But the hook is not called up when we change the 'region' of blocks in page 'admin/structure/block'.

Are there any other methods other than injecting an extra submit handler to the form displayed in 'admin/structure/block' page?

Comment: what you want to do ?

Comment: Certain blocks are dynamically created and those will have corresponding nodes. Change in block configurations have to be reflected in node's fields too.

Answer (score 3):

The [`block_admin_display_form_submit()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.admin.inc/function/block_admin_display_form_submit/7) function (submit handler for the block admin form) manipulates the region value for the blocks in the database directly, and doesn't invoke any hooks.

That being said, the only 'good' way you're going to be able to do this is to add an additional submit handler to the form in a `form_alter` hook as you've suggested.

Comment: yes, I chose that method.